# 504 gateway timeout while runnning the Load Test jmeter

Tags: nginx, jmeter, gateway

I have been working on performing the load test on jmeter for 500 users per second. I am using JMeter for the same. While running the load test I am continuously getting the error on login API.
Below is the request and response which I am sending and receiving timeout.

**Sample Request**

```
POST https://example.com//9000/v1/api/user/login

POST data:
{
        "email":"xyz@yopmail.com",
        "password":"abcdef"
}

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
: 
Content-Length: 79
Host: botstest.smartbothub.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)
```

**sample response**

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-310
Sample Start: 2017-12-27 11:30:06 IST
Load time: 61422
Connect Time: 1148
Latency: 61422
Size in bytes: 363
Sent bytes:286
Headers size in bytes: 171
Body size in bytes: 192
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 504
Response message: Gateway Time-out

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 06:01:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Connection: keep-alive


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: null
```

The nginx config file for the server is as shown below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_XWYeqSAWZz6dtnTTCeLOEMzDwvEWwY1/view

Comment: A 504 probably means that nginx ( or the upstream application ) is under high load and can not properly respond.

Comment: so how to fix this do I need to change my nginx configuration for same?

Comment: Configuration? Probably not much to do. You can check the [tuning guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/). But my guess is that the physical server you are running on is probably overloaded. Check CPU usage of the server.

Comment: you need to increase timeout in ngynx more than 60 seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your Nginx server is overloaded therefore request cannot be processed in the timely fashion causing the error.

It might be caused by several issues:

1. Nginx server simply lacks hardware resources (CPU, RAM, Network or Disk). Make sure it has enough headroom to operate by monitoring the aforementioned resources on Nginx side using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Nginx server configuration is not suitable for high loads. Default configuration might not be suitable for handling 500 concurrent users so check out [How to Configure nginx for Optimized Performance](https://linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/configure-nginx-for-optimized-performance/) article to see whether your setup matches recommendations. Basically you need to combine points 1 and 2 to get most of your Nginx setup, if the machine is relatively idle and you're getting high response times and/or low throughput - something is wrong either with your web application or with infrastructure setup.
3. It might be a problem with your application which cannot generate response faster than Nginx times out. Check out its logs and inspect what's going on using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) - it will allow you to detect where application spends the most of time
4. It might be an network infrastructure problem, i.e. you're using WiFi instead of LAN or there is a faulty router or you reached the limits of corporate proxy. It might be also a good idea to capture network traffic using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

But first of all **read logs**: JMeter logs, Nginx logs, OS logs, whatever exists and relevant. Most probably you will figure out the cause from them.